# AngularJS module split among iFrames within single page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have a webapp with 1 module, 5 pages and 5 controllers. Each HTML page declare the same ng-app.

The pages are loaded within widgets in a web portal; that is, each page is loaded within an iFrame in the portal. The 5 controllers use the same service, but because each page is loaded in a iFrame, the service is instanciated 5 times.

I'm not familiar with AngularJS but I'm pretty sure there must be a clean way to do this. I don't want to load 5 times my app.js, 5 times my service...

I searched through the web for hours, couldn't find anything.

Comment: why are you using iframes ?? use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: This ain't my choice. The web portal I'm using instantiate a new iFrame each time you open a widget, and this iFrame points to the HTML page that is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I understand it, is that you're trying to use an external menu to navigate through your angular app within an iframe? Resulting in a request of a different HTML page on your server everytime your users clicks your menu?

This implies you're invoking 5 different HTML pages on your server, whom invoke each in their turn the ng-app directive, thus (re)instantiating your appplication.

To prevent this from happening you shouldn't invoke a request of every single html page but request the application once by loading an index page and providing routes within your application, where the user can navigate through.

Here is a `plunker` [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6cwmkf?p=preview) using [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

Comment: Thanks, I came across ng-route during my researches, but this one example made me realize it's what I need in my case. I'll give this a try.